# Disable/Enable onClick Event after Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-events

I am using the Jquery Validation 1.9.0 Plugin to validate my forms before they are submitted.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

I have Google Event Tracking code on the form submit button in an `onClick` attribute that I don't want to fire until the form validation is complete and the form actually submits to have better accuracy on the data Google tracks.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Form Submit', 'Button Click', 'A visitor has filled out the form.');">Submit</button>
```

What is a clean method to prevent the function within the `onClick` attribute from firing, once the form validation is complete the form will submit, but just prior to submitting it should fire the `ga` event tracking code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) option of the `$.validate` call.  It only gets triggered when the form is valid:

```
$(form).validate({
   //your usual stuff here
   submitHandler: function(){
     ga('send', 'event', 'Form Submit', 'Button Click', 'A visitor has filled out the form.');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fire the analytics event on your form submit event after validating the form:

On your form add a onsubmit event:

```
<form onsubmit="submitMyForm(this);return false;">...</form>
```

The best would be to do this in a method first.  Id have a function in your forms onsubmit liek this:

```
funtion submitMyForm(form)
{
    if ($(form).valid())
    {
       ga('send', 'event', 'Form Submit', 'Button Click', 'A visitor has filled out the form.');

      $(form).submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: The library has a specific event for handling this.